# Differences accessing a model using singular and plural model name on cakePHP

Tags: cakephp, model, naming-conventions

What is the different uses between singular and plural model name?. If we have a model named Catalogue, saved as catalog.php. Then, we have a controller. If we use "$uses" variable to define which model should involved, see code bellow:

```
class CataloguesController extends AppController {
    var $name = 'Catalogues';
    var $uses = array('Hierarchy', 'Catalogue', 'Catalogues');
}
```

I have mentioned above, that the related model only a Catalogue.

What is the differences accessing with:

```
$queried = $this->Catalogues->find('all');
```

or

```
$queried = $this->Catalogue->find('all');
```

Comment: In a word, convention. Cake assumes that model names will be singular. Try to fight the convention as little as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is that the plural form of the model is invalid. Model names are always singular.

Comment: Correct, the convention names should be singular for model. But if we use plural model name (Condition: we only have Catalogue.php), using 'Catalogues' will make same result as 'Catalogue' model. Why cakePHP, allow to access plural Model name (see my pre conditions).

Comment: I don't understand you question, then. The convention is that the model is singular. If Cake lets you access it using a plural form, it's a side effect or a bug. As to the question "what is the difference" - there is none, other than the plural is not guaranteed to always work.

Comment: I'm totally agreed, maybe it's a side affect or a bug. I just wonder is cakePHP allow it for some purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Also - if your model's table is catalogues, the model name should be Catalogue and the filename should be catalogue.php.

Your file name doesn't match your model name.

Comment: Yes, i have table named 'catalogues'. And also have model named 'Catalogue'. Why cakePHP allow access that model using both 'Catalogue' and 'Catalogues'?

Comment: It isn't - when you reference Catalogues it is almost certainly an instance of AppModel and not Catalogue.

Comment: An instance of AppModel?. So, why it can provide access to 'catalogues' table. I forgot to mention, that both of statements above returning same result.

Comment: If you try and call a model that doesn't have a model file but does have a corresponding db table cake will use an instance of AppModel automatically. Try seeing if each of the two models is an instance of AppModel or itself. Otherwise, I would maybe check into the Inflector and see if it might be acting up on that word.